# Similar search text with mongoose(like sql we can use like query)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I try **Similar Search** text  with mongoose;but i cant get result like this:

```
    var x="ol"//in database value is "olala"
    topic.find( { $text: { $search:x } }).exec(function(err,ss){
                     if(ss){console.log(ss)}

                 })
```

if i try like this i can get result.If x same as database value i can get result.In php- we use %(modulus) for **Similar Search**:

```
var x="olala"
    topic.find( { $text: { $search:x } }).exec(function(err,ss){
                     if(ss){console.log(ss)}

                 })
```

Comment: Use regex ? 
topic.find({"text" : {$regex : ".*ola.*"}});

Comment: Can i add isensitive?Ty @RITESH

Comment: Ok i find (?i) this operator make isensitive:D

Comment: yes regex has "i" which means insensitive :)

Comment: or use $options:'i' .I always read quickly:D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the only other way is regex 
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/